# Left and Right vs. Substring() in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Which one would you prefer to extract a sub-string from the given string and why?

I am thinking that since `Left` and `Right` are VB functions and not .NET functions, they may cause problems in the future in terms of compatibility.

Please clarify my thoughts on that.

Comment: Are you using .NET or an older version of VB?

Comment: I am using .NET and it needs Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace.

Comment: I do believe that you can use Substring with a negative length, simulating the same behaviour. But I would use standard .NET functions, unless I really did need something else.

Comment: I started programming in BASIC (when I was 12), and for years would roll my own `Left`and `Right` functions for languages that didn't have them. The can be useful abstractions for certain string handling scenarios.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use whichever makes most sense i.e. makes that piece of code easier to read.

I don't know why you'd think that they'd cause problems in the future, they're functions, they're provided as part of the VB.Net Language set, there is *no earthly reason* why they would be removed, and even if they were, **they would be trivial to re-implement**.

Use 'em, cause you ain't gonna lose 'em

Answer (score 3):

When given the choice between a feature that is from [`Microsoft.VisualBasic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.aspx) vs a comparable feature that is provided in the core framework assembiles, I tend to stick with the latter in most cases.

I do this for various reasons:

- It tends to be understood by more developers. (e.g. C# guy looking at my VB.NET code).
- You're more likely to find online help (message boards, stackoverflow, etc) for the core framework version than you are for the VB-ized version.
- Using them gives your code a "legacy" feeling to it.  It's like making use of the [`Call`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxz296wz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) statement.
- Makes it easier for another person to "copy and paste" VB.Net code into their C# (or other .NET language) project and have it be one less language translation point/hangup. (Unlikely this is a real concern/reason, but I know I've many-a-time "copy and pasted" example C# code into my VB.Net project and anything that doesn't cause road blocks in the translation process (e.g. usage of `yield`) makes my life easier.)
- While **completely inconceivable** they are going away (as most of these keywords/statements are a BASIC language construct), they do *feel* more likely to become marked obsolete than any of their core framework counterparts. Especially as VB6 is becoming more and more of a distant memory and the VB.NET language takes on a life of its own in conjunction with the core .NET framework advancing.

One notable exception to this, I tend to make use of the [`My` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.myservices.aspx) proxies offered; `My.FileSystem.ReadAllText(...)` is just sexy. :P

Comment: Sorry, but you've a couple of very tenuous arguments in there. 1) Why would code need to be ported to _another_ .net language? Isn't that what the CLR is all about, that languages don't really matter? And even if it does, there's nothing stopping a C# assembly from referencing the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace and using the left & right functions from there. 2) You're last point, which is a "feeling" - is unwarranted, those functions are part of the BASIC language, they're not going anywhere, they're as likely to remove the `switch` statement from C#.

Comment: ckittel: I'm likin' the edits. All my concerns have been nicely deflected :)

Comment: @Binary Thanks, your comments were very constructive, and I took them into consideration in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: P.S. + 1 for `My` sexiness :)

Comment: Actually I should say I use `Call` much more in VB.NET than I ever did in VB6 and below -- not much in production code, but often in LinqPad because of the syntax issue of not being able to call an expression's method without it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you work alone?

If no, the decision is simple.

- If your team members have **C# background**, use `Substring`.
- If your devs have some **VB6 background**, use `Left` and `Right`.
- If you ain't sure, ask them.

Comment: I would be very surprised if any developer coming from any 3GL had any difficulty figuring out what Left & Right functions do. It's not like the names are ambiguous :)

Comment: That's probably true. Personally, I would prefer `Left` and `Right` in .NET Framework but perhaps this is because I'm coming from VB6.

Comment: I've been programming professionally for almost 20 years, in a variety of languages and with folks from many backgrounds, trust me, `Left` & `Right` functions don't cause much confusion :)

Comment: Hand-E-Food: Bah! You'd never use `Left` & `Right` for right-to-left languages! You'd obviously use `Right` & `Left` :)

Answer (score 0):

.net SubString will throw if start + length is > than the string length where VB Left() will return the entire string if a length greater than the string length is provided. That's a substantial behavioral difference.

Also, given .Net Standard, avoid Microsoft.VisualBasic.

Yes, I know this is > 10 years old, but ended up here when trying to port some really old code. So, thought I'd share the difference.